# R mschart predefine the color of line chart

Tags: r, mschart

ex: When I have the line chart, What I want to display the color is ("green" is for the line a, "purple" is for the line b), is it feasible in the R mschart?
    library(officer)
    library(mschart)
    library(dplyr)

```
data <- data.frame(Name=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                   wave_id=c("2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4","2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4"),
pct=c(0.68,0.71,0.70,0.72,0.57,0.57,0.57,0.58))

data1 <- data%>%
  ms_linechart(x="wave_id",y="pct",group="Name")%>%
  chart_labels(title=NULL,xlab=" ",ylab=" ")%>%
  chart_ax_y(limit_min = 0.4,limit=0.8,
             num_fmt='0%%',major_tick_mark="none",minor_tick_mark="none")

data1_theme<- mschart_theme(
  axis_title = fp_text(font.size=1),
  legend_position = "r",
  grid_major_line=fp_border(width=))

pptsdata1 <- set_theme(data1, data1_theme)

doc <- read_pptx()

doc <-doc%>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")%>%
  ph_with_chart_at(chart=pptsdata1, left=1,  top=1,  height=3,  width=8)

print(doc, target = "my_plot.pptx")
```

Comment: In MSChart the color of a line is determined by the color of the line's endpoint (DataPoint). Can't help with `r`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following with the creation of ms_linechart:

```
data1 <- data%>%
  ms_linechart(x="wave_id",y="pct",group="Name")%>%
  chart_labels(title=NULL,xlab=" ",ylab=" ")%>%
  chart_data_stroke(my_colors) %>%
  chart_ax_y(limit_min = 0.4,limit=0.8,
         num_fmt='0%%',major_tick_mark="none",minor_tick_mark="none")
```

where `my_colors` is a list of specified colors, like

```
my_colors <- list(
    a = "green",
    b = "purple"
  )
```

a and b were the names of the lines